# GUID parameter for entitydatasource in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, entitydatasource

I want to know how I can set a GUID parameter for my entitydatasource. This is what I have currently:

```
 <asp:EntityDataSource ID="AccountsEntityDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="name=AccountsEntities" 
        DefaultContainerName="AccountsEntities" EnableDelete="True" 
        EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" Where="it.BatchID = @BatchID"
        EntitySetName="Accounts">
          <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="BatchID" Type="String" />
    </WhereParameters>
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

In the backend I have this:

```
AccountsEntityDataSource.WhereParameters("BatchID").DefaultValue = Request.QueryString("BatchID")
```

And I'm getting this error:

> The argument types 'Edm.Guid' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for
>   this operation. Near WHERE predicate, line 6, column 12.

Any idea what can I change?

Answer (score 0):

You can escape it with the keyword `GUID` followed by a space i.e.

```
Where="it.BatchID = GUID '@BatchID'"
```

[**MSDN Reference**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399176.aspx)